# How to Suspend a Workflow (Declarative Service Library) Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4

**Scenario**

- DeclarativeServiceLibrary[FlowChart]

  - with Two Recieve - Send Reply Activities
  - persistence enabled and working
- WebApplication

  - "Service Reference" is above mentioned declarative service library

**Question**

- Is there anyway to Suspend workflow after receiving reply from first activity ?
- Whether it is possible via exposed WCF Service method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by adding a WorkflowControlEndpoint to the workflow service. Use a WorkflowControlClient at the client side to suspend, or abort etc, the workflow instance using the workflow instance id.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx) for more details. If you are using the AppFabric the WorkflowControlEndpoint is automatically added and configured using the NetNamedPipeBinding binding but you can use another binding if you like.

Comment: thank you for showing right direction. I'll checkout WorkflowControlEndPoint... I'm not using AppFabrice, may be in future!